# Testng reporting all tests from 2 classes in the first class

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, maven, testng

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="MasterTest" **parallel="tests" thread-count="3"** verbose="1">
    <parameter name="runLocal" value="false" />
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="SupportReport" />
    </listeners>
    <test name="Firefox Tests">
        <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
        <classes>
            <class name="CalculatorTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Chrome Tests">
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
        <classes>
            <class name="CalculatorTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

the above testng.xml is not verbatim... I took out class path details.

there are 12 @tests in CalculatorTest.  They run in parallel remotely on Selenium Grid Hub (2 nodes) and the console shows they all run successfully.

So 24 total tests execute, the emailable report only contains the 12 tests for testname: Firefox Tests.

When I check the Testng-results.xml in the surefire folder it has all 24 tests listed for the first testname (Firefox Tests).  there is no reference to "Chrome Tests" testname.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzhvF.png)

Here is the twist....  for many runs I do get correct reporting.  2 sections in the emailable report one for Firefox Tests and 1 for Chrome Tests.  each containing 12 tests.

Pretty sure this will not be a problem in test environments and production as they will not be run so much like in dev.

What I would really like to know is how is this possible?  what are the inner workings of Testng when it comes to keeping track of suites, test methods, results etc.

I can see the report listener extract these artifacts from the context, list/map of suites and results.

Also I have overridden the generatereport method, but as far as I can see, only the Firefox Test tests are available to report on.

Who is the expert that might enlighten me on this topic?  I will be supporting the creation and reporting of tests for the foreseeable future :)  So I am really curious about many aspects of Testng.

many thanks and warm regards,

DJ

Comment: Its not clear as to what is your issue. Can you please edit your question and add details?
It would be good if you could attach a simple standalone test project that can be used to reproduce the problem that you are experiencing. Also make sure you are using the latest released version of TestNG `7.1.0` (as of today)

Answer (score 0):

sorry for slow response.  I was away from home for a couple of days.

Thank you for your reply KM.  I see that you answer many, many questions.  I appreciate any efforts you might make on my behalf in this matter.

As for reproducing, this is not a consistent behavior.  As I am still in the development phase, I run the suite several times.  At first I see all 24 tests reported.  After some time only 12 tests are reported.  So it works until it doesn't.

Again, these tests are executed on a remote Selenium Grid Hub with a separate node for each browser (Chrome and firefox).

the problem is 24 tests are executed and only 12 test are available in suite object.

Do you know how Testng could NOT put executed tests results in the suites list?

```
from CustomEmailableReporter:


protected void generateMethodDetailReport(List<ISuite> suites) {    
    m_methodIndex = 0;
    for (ISuite suite : suites) {
        Map<String, ISuiteResult> r = suite.getResults();
        for (ISuiteResult r2 : r.values()) {
            ITestContext testContext = r2.getTestContext();
```

.
.
.

A typical test:

```
@Test(priority = 4, dependsOnMethods = { "gettingStartedPage" })
public void childInfoPAge() {

    ChildInfoPage childInfoPage = null;
    stalenessCheck("childGroup");

    // ensure that the page factory is created
    try {
        childInfoPage = new ChildInfoPage(driver);
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        assertionErrorText = "ERROR:The creation of the ChildInfoPage pagefactory failed";
        Assert.fail(assertionErrorText);
    }

    // ensure that fields are clickable
    assertTrue(isClickable(driver.findElement(By.id("overnightsSpent")), driver));

    // exercise the screen field(s)
    childInfoAPage.overnightSpent.type("78");
    driver.findElement(By.id("ContinueBtn")).click();

    // check for client-side errors
    errorTrap();

    logCalcMessage("childInfoPage", "Test Complete");
    logMessage("------------------------------------------------");
}
```